# Unity application doesn't run on iOS due to Shader warning and Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and trying to get a VERY simple 2D game to work through `Xcode`. Everything seems to be working and the build is successful. But, it is printing the errors below -

```
2019-10-23 22:27:16.559673-0600 test4[19600:5249871] Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.9f1 (ebce4d76e6e8)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
    2019-10-23 22:27:16.569618-0600 test4[19600:5249871] -> registered mono modules 0x102e52fd0
    -> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
    2019-10-23 22:27:17.523747-0600 test4[19600:5249871] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
    -> applicationDidBecomeActive()
    GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
    Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A12 GPU
    Initialize engine version: 2019.2.9f1 (ebce4d76e6e8)
    WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-GUITexture' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
    2019-10-23 22:27:20.289401-0600 test4[19600:5250073] Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
    2019-10-23 22:27:20.301490-0600 test4[19600:5250073] Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
    2019-10-23 22:27:20.309975-0600 test4[19600:5250073] Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
    2019-10-23 22:27:20.310028-0600 test4[19600:5250073] MTLCompiler: Compilation failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED on 3 try
    Metal: Error creating pipeline state (Hidden/Internal-GUITexture): Compiler encountered an internal error
    (null)2019-10-23 22:27:30.388420-0600 test4[19600:5249871] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SplashScreenController: 0x105c0ab00>.
    UnloadTime: 0.146417 ms
    WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitCopy' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
    WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitCopy' - Setting to default shader.
    2019-10-23 22:27:31.854057-0600 test4[19600:5250073] Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
    2019-10-23 22:27:40.897804-0600 test4[19600:5250073] Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
    2019-10-23 22:27:50.936250-0600 test4[19600:5250073] Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
    2019-10-23 22:27:50.936525-0600 test4[19600:5250073] MTLCompiler: Compilation failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED on 3 try
    Metal: Error creating pipeline state (UI/Default): Compiler encountered an internal error
    (null)
```

After a few minutes the black screen turns to blue and nothing happens. I have tried to turn all the shaders to no support but that didn't work. I am unable to find anyone with similar issue. I find others with shader issues but they seem to fix it with the switch to "no support". Also, the game runs just fine on Unity as well as on my iPhone XR with Unity controller app.

I am using Xcode 11 and Unity 2.1.2. I am trying to run the game on my iPhone XR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with MacOS Catalina, the guys here are discussing it: 
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios?page=1#comments

The solution for me was to change Color Space to Linear instead of Gamma in project settings.

Comment: This worked! And super nice to have that link with the live issue and other people's comments. Googled everywhere and never found it so thanks a ton. The game works and runs but the UI Labels/text is all pink blocks. Any thoughts on how to fix that? Or is that just part of the same issue Unity is working on?

Comment: Oh never mind. I just need to switch my project settings>graphics>"always include shaders" 0 and 1 back to their defaults (sprites/default and UI/default). works perfect! thanks again!

Comment: The problem not only applies to iOS, but also to Android. Although this solution works, you can't use opengles 2.0 with linear color space. This obviously restricts how many devices your app can run on.

Answer (score -1):

Unity 2019.3b fixes this issue on Android and iOS as well.

Comment: I'm still having this issue on Unity 2020.1.13